# How to provide Type hint for cellRendererParams in ag-grid angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

I have created multiple `CellRenderer`s for using with `ag-grid`. But one problem I frequently face is that I have to remember what parameters and types a specific `CellRenderer` takes. Is there any way to use TypeScript capabilities to add Type hint to `cellRendererParams`? It would definitely improve the coding experience.

For reference, ag-grid cellRendereParams are passed as key-value pairs as the following:

```
{
  field: 'colour',
  cellRenderer: ColourRenderer,
  cellRendererParams: {
    colourName: 'yellow',
    opacity: 0.9
  }
}
```

I would like my editor to show hint that `ColourRenderer` takes 2 parameters `colourName` and `opacity` and their types are `string` and `number`. Thanks

N.B: I am using the latest **ag-grid** with **Angular 9**

Comment: Please create a plnkr.io or stackblitz.io demo for angular questions. You can use the plnkr links on the ag-grid documentation as a starting point

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer your question directly, but I do have a functional alternative, at least one that works for me...

Ag-Grid's API clearly was not written with types in mind, and even the Angular wrapper is so thin that it's a genuine challenge to use it in a type-safe way.

So, after working with it for well over a year, I decided to write my own wrapper.
Part of that was a ColumnDefinition class, which implements ag-grid's ColDef interface.
My ColumnDefinition class has 'builder' methods that add features to the ColumnDefinition instance.

This allows me to have methods, with typed parameters, to build things like cellRenders, rather than just using literals.

So, for example, if I were to implement support for your ColourRenderer in my ColumnDefintion class, I would create a method with the following signature:

```
public withColourRenderer(colourName: text, opacity: number): ColumnDefinition
```

and that way, once you have used other methods to create a ColumnDefinition, you could call this method to add the renderer, and you would get the type hints.

To give you an idea, building one column like that might look something like this:

```
ColumnDefintion.stringColumnForField('colour', 'Colour')
   .sortable()
   .filterable()
   .withEditor()
   .withColourRenderer(colourName: 'yellow', opacity: 0.9);
```

Comment: That's a really nice solution. But in my current use case, creating a wrapper over ag-grid would be too big of a solution to solve a too small problem. But I really like this approach and will definitely consider in future cases. But for now let's see if I can find anything simpler. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

This is meh but it works for me:

```
cellRendererParams: { hideTime: true } as IMaGridCellRenderDateProps }
```